# Why I can I edit but not append a unix file

Tags: ubuntu, logging, permissions

Feeling pretty dumb.  With the same user **I am able to edit a file via vi**, but I get permission errors when appending to the file.  **What am I doing wrong.**  I would like to append to this file!

```
ls -alt /var/log
drwxr-xr-x 11 root      root     4096 May 14 01:20 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 root      root        6 May 14 01:20 money-worker.log

sudo echo "hello" >> /var/log/money-worker.log
-bash: /var/log/money-worker.log: Permission denied

whoami
ubuntu
```

I am running ubuntu 12.04, and sshing in

Love some tips.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because:

```
sudo echo "hello" >> /var/log/money-worker.log
```

means:

```
( sudo echo "hello" ) >> /var/log/money-worker.log
```

not:

```
sudo ( echo "hello" >> /var/log/money-worker.log )
```

In other words, the appending is being attempted by the shell *before* `sudo` runs. The shell will (attempt to) open the file for append then "attach" that to the `sudo` stanadard output.

As a workaround, you could try something like:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "hello" >> /var/log/money-worker.log'
```

which will run the entire `bash`-with-arguments-and-redirections under the control of `sudo`.

Comment: I guess this is why you have greater than 250k!  Thanks alot for the quick response AND the quick edits to include the work around!

Comment: And for those that are dealing with this with upstart (init conf files).  This is important to read as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8903051/192791

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `sudo` call affects echo but not the permission on the file. In other words the command executes and then outputs (and `sudo` ends) then it tries to redirect that output to the file.

You could get around this by putting `echo "hello" >> /var/log/money-worker.log` into a file and then doing `sudo yourscript.sh`

Or just change ownership of the file